# What does the fraction equal?

Tags: word

Here is a puzzle I just heard about.

```
Nebuchadnezzar x  Methuselah
---------------------------    =   ?
    Melchior + Balthazar
```

Comment: Looks like you have quite a few valid potential answers!

Comment: I think dr jimbob's is clearly the intended one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These are

> large wine bottle sizes specific for sparkling wine.

Specifically,

> Melchior = 24 standard bottles,
>  Nebuchadnezzar = 20 standard bottles,
>  Balthazar = 16 standard bottles,
>  Methuselah = 8 standard bottles,
>  *Jeroboam* = 4 standard bottles.
>  [Source](https://www.vintageroots.co.uk/blog/guide-to-wine-bottle-sizes/)

So the math works out to give

> $\frac{20 \mathrm{bottles} \times 8 \mathrm{bottles}}{24\mathrm{bottles}+16 \mathrm{bottles}} = \frac{160\mathrm{bottles}^{2}}{40\mathrm{bottles}} = 4 \mathrm{bottles}$

Which going back to the word equivalency we find is equal to the word:

> Jeroboam

Comment: (Thanks.  Was having trouble getting the spoiler formatting working.)

Comment: No problem! The spoilers are funny, they are indeed >! but you can't have consecutive lines of >! unless you have <pre> or some funny code before and after it. I like personally spacing things out with non-spoiler words.

Comment: This is definitely the right answer in my view. Congratulations.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is

> 306.

This is because

> of the ages of the men when they died: Nebuchadnezzar was 72; Methuselah was 969; Melchior was 116; and Balthazar was 112.

So the math works out to

> $\frac{72 \times 969}{116 + 112} = 306$.

Comment: Wow.  Even though this wasn't the answer, it's pretty remarkable that you got an integer out of that.

Comment: @greenturtle3141 I was stunned when it worked out like that — to be honest, if it didn’t I might’ve not posted it haha!

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if my answer is right, but this could be a variation

> If we take the number word of each word (i.e. a=1, 26=z) and do the math we get: **(148*112)/(83+89)**, to **96.3720930233**